# How to add custom adapter using ArrayAdapter?

Tags: android, web-services, android-arrayadapter, custom-adapter

I am trying to add custom adapter where i want to add folder image and name of that particular folder which is I am getting from web services.

Please see my code:

```
ListView listview;
LazyAdapter adapter;

private String[] folderslist;

String User_ID;
int i;

static String ID = "ID";
static String KEY_Name = "FolderName";
static String ParentID = "ParentID";
static String CreatedBy = "CreatedBy";                               

private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static final String URL = "http://***.***.*.*/somethinghere/something.asmx";
private static final String TREEDATA_METHOD = "TreeData";
private static final String SOAP_ACTION_TREEDATA = "http://tempuri.org/TreeData";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.homepage_layout);

    Intent Intent = getIntent();
    User_ID = Intent.getStringExtra("User_ID");

    Treedata();

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

            String item = (String) listview.getItemAtPosition(position);
            ID = item;          
            Intent mIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Files_Folders_Activity.class);
            mIntent.putExtra("ID", ID);

            startActivity(mIntent);

        }
    });

}

        public void Treedata(){
            try {

                SoapObject datarequest = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, TREEDATA_METHOD);

                datarequest.addProperty("UserID", User_ID);

                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                envelope.dotNet = true;
                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(datarequest);

                HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION_TREEDATA, envelope);

                SoapObject folderResponse = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();

                Log.i("AllFolders", folderResponse.toString());

                folderslist = new String[folderResponse.getPropertyCount()];

                for(i=0; i<folderResponse.getPropertyCount(); i++) {

                    SoapObject SingleFolder = (SoapObject)folderResponse.getProperty(i);

                    Log.i("SingleFolder", SingleFolder.toString());

                    ID= SingleFolder.getProperty(0).toString();
                    KEY_Name = SingleFolder.getProperty(1).toString();
                    ParentID = SingleFolder.getProperty(2).toString();
                    CreatedBy= SingleFolder.getProperty(3).toString();                      

                    folderslist[i] = SingleFolder.getProperty(0).toString();

                    folderslist = new String[] {ID};

                   }

                    data = new ArrayList<FolderList>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < folderslist.length; i++) {

                    FolderList item = new FolderList(images[i], folderslist[i]);
                    data.add(item);

            }   
                    listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);

                    LazyAdapter adapter = new LazyAdapter(this, R.layout.jpg_row, data);

                    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

                    listview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
            }

        }
```

LazyAdapter:

```
public class LazyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FolderList> {

Context context;

public LazyAdapter(Context context, int resourceId, List<FolderList> items) {
    super(context, resourceId, items);
    this.context = context;
}

/*private view holder class*/
private class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView txtTitle;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    FolderList data = getItem(position);

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.jpg_row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    holder.txtTitle.setText(data.getTitle());
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(data.getIcon());

    return convertView;
}
```

}

I am using string[] to get web response and then property 1 which id folder name. Can anybody let me know how can I add custom list, in which it shows folder image and name of folder or can guide in right way? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First No Need to Set your adapter inside for loop. it will set your adapter to listview every time you run for loop. your code is not wrong but also not efficient. you should set your ArrayAdapter Outside for loop by Below Way.

```
     for(i=0; i<folderResponse.getPropertyCount(); i++) {

                        SoapObject SingleFolder = (SoapObject)folderResponse.getProperty(i);

                        Log.i("SingleFolder", SingleFolder.toString());

                        ID= SingleFolder.getProperty(0).toString();
                        KEY_Name = SingleFolder.getProperty(1).toString();
                        ParentID = SingleFolder.getProperty(2).toString();
                        CreatedBy= SingleFolder.getProperty(3).toString();

                        System.out.println(ID);
                        System.out.println(KEY_Name);
                        System.out.println(ParentID);
                        System.out.println(CreatedBy);

                        folderslist[i] = SingleFolder.getProperty(0).toString();


                }
          listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,   android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1, folderslist);

        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        listview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Also if you want to Make it Custom list with folder image and name of folder you should Use BaseAdater instead of ArrayAdapter.

you will get Better Idea from [Custom Listview with BaseAdapter Sample Demo](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/) how you can Use Custom list with BaseAdapter.
Hope it will Help.

Comment: I want custom adapter, List is showing. Issue is I want to use custom adapter to display folder image and name of folders from web services

Comment: I was following this tutorial but not got any solution. I don't know how to use string[count]; into Hashmap<>, So I used ArrayAdapter<> actually.